# createAsyncThunk: dispatch more actions after updating store with fetched data, within a same payload creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I just started using **Redux Toolkit(RTK)**, and I'm having a hard time figuring out a proper way of using `createAsyncThunk` from RTK.

So what I'm trying to do is to

1. **dispatch an asynchronous action created by `createAsyncThunk`**
2. **update store with fetched data,**
3. **and dispatch another synchronous action within a same payload creator.**

For example, you could write such code with `redux-saga` like below.

```js
function* fetchBooksSaga() {
  try {
    yield put(fetchBooksStart()); // set loading
    const keyword = yield select(state => state.keyword); // get keyword from store
    const { data } = yield call(SearchBooksAPI, query); // fetch books
    yield put(fetchBooksSuccess(data)); // set books
    
    // Here, you can dispatch another action with newly updated state.
    const books = yield select(state => state.books);

    // I know you can just use 'data' variable here,
    // but let's say you have to update store first.
    yield put(anotherAction(books)); 
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchBooksFailure(error)); // set error
  }
}
```

I was trying to write same code with `createAsyncThunk`, and the result looks like below.

```js
export const fetchBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  'BOOKS/FETCH_BOOKS',
  async (params, ThunkAPI) => {
    try {
      // when 'fetchBooks' is dispatched, fetchBooks.pending will be dispatched automatically.
      const { keyword } = ThunkAPI.getState(); // get keyword from store.
      const { data } = await SearchBooksAPI(query); // fetch books
      ThunkAPI.dispatch(fetchBooks.fulfilled(data)); // set books
      
      // store updated at this moment

      const { books } = ThunkAPI.getState();
      ThunkAPI.dispatch(anotherAction(books));
      
      // NOPE - returning value here will dispatch fetchBooks.fulfilled again.
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      ThunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error); // dispatch fetchBooks.rejected
    }
  }
);
```

Like its name, payload creator should create a payload. So it's obvious that I should return something within a payload creator. But in this case, returning value will dispatch `asyncAction.fulfilled` again, with returned value wrapped by Promise as payload.

I could just use a normal thunk action or saga, but the reason I'm trying this way is to minimize boilerplate. Using a normal thunk action will require to create action creators for pending/success/failure, which is not necessary when using `createAsyncThunk`.

Does anyone have idea that could help me solve this issue? any comments will be appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createAsyncThunk` isn't quite meant for that use case.  It's specifically meant to handle the "fetch data and dispatch result" use case, not an ongoing sequence of dispatches.

You *do* have access to `thunkAPI.dispatch` inside of the payload creation callback, so you could dispatch additional actions *before* the `fulfilled` action is dispatched.  But, the `fulfilled` action won't get dispatched until the returned promise resolves, so it doesn't give you the ability to dispatch more actions *after* that is done.

The closest thing I can think of at the moment would be something like this:

```js
export const fetchBooks = createAsyncThunk(
  'BOOKS/FETCH_BOOKS',
  async (params, ThunkAPI) => {
    try {
      // when 'fetchBooks' is dispatched, fetchBooks.pending will be dispatched automatically.
      const { keyword } = ThunkAPI.getState(); // get keyword from store.
      const { data } = await SearchBooksAPI(query); // fetch books
      
      const resultPromise = Promise.resolve(data);
      
      resultPromise.then(() => {
        const { books } = ThunkAPI.getState();
        ThunkAPI.dispatch(anotherAction(books));
      })
      
      return resultPromise;
    } catch (error) {
      ThunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error); // dispatch fetchBooks.rejected
    }
  }
);
```

but I'm not sure the timing on that will be entirely correct with when that promise resolves and when the `fulfilled` action gets dispatched.

I think your best option here would be to break this into two thunks: one that does just the normal fetch+dispatch for the original data, and a second thunk that dispatches the first one and then does the additional logic.